# "Use (create mode)" button is missing

Tags: civimember, custom-fields

WordPress 5.2.2, Civi 5.15.1

I just created a custom profile containing custom Membership fields, and want to get its URL so I can add it to the Navigation Menu. However, the Use button does not appear on the profile's field list page. In the past I have created other custom profiles containing all Contact fields, and never encountered this problem. Is there something special about Membership profiles, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's intentional that there are no links if there's mixed record types in a profile.

It's been like that for a LONG time:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-1974

Also for reference: 
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.15.1/CRM/UF/Page/Group.php#L353

UPDATE: Based on the comments, I think this is what is desired:

1. Create a profile that has just the membership fields.
2. On the manage contribution pages, on the profile tab for your membership contribution page, include the profile either at top or bottom.
3. When the person goes to buy their membership using your contribution page they'll see the custom fields from your profile.

Comment: My profile has only Membership fields—it is not mixed with other types. Although, at some point it must be associated with a Contact, so I guess that's where the mixing comes in. Regardless, if one can't customize Memberships like Contacts, then how? My org runs a CSA program (community-supported agriculture), where customers get a box of veggies every week, which they pick up at a location they choose. Where can we record this location? Is the only option to create a different Membership Type for each location? I scoured the User Guide but must've missed something. Thanks, Demerit.

Comment: In your setup can a single contact have more than one membership? If not, then can you just have the location be a custom field on the contact? If they do have multiple memberships, then would probably need more information about how you're using memberships, and then might be best to post that as a separate question so it gets more visibility. Do you mean they create a new membership each week for each contact, possibly with a different location?

Comment: >1 Memberships (e.g. a big, vegan family) are too rare to deal with, & would be unrelated to Location anyway (it's static over the Membership duration). Not all Contacts are CSA members, some CSA members are also donors, volunteers, etc. So creating a custom CSA Contact subtype/profile with a Location field would cause more problems than it solves (though I did consider it). I'm surprised the UserGuide would mention custom fields and Memberships in the same context if there's no actual way to get the former into the latter. Any more ideas? If not, I'll just do 1 Type per Location. Thx again!

Comment: Ok I think I see what you're trying to do now. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: I should've stressed that the reason I wanted the profile added to the nav bar is that we are purely standalone Civi users. We won't publish anything from Civi on our website until this farm season's over (at which point we'll have to integrate with or replace our existing WooCommerce plugin). Until then we have to enter all new Contacts and Memberships through the Civi interface. Since our WooCommerce setup involves a separate product for each Pickup Location, I'm tempted to mirror that in Civi and be done with it, unless you have another solution in mind. Much appreciated, @Demerit.

Comment: Oh then do you need profiles? Can you enter memberships from the Memberships - New Membership menu choice, which will show your custom fields?

Comment: Wow, don't I feel like a doofus. Due to my small monitor (and assuming creating a profile was the correct next step) I didn't notice the custom fieldset appearing at the bottom when the membership type is selected. Thanks again, and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Ha ha. No worries.